# Get value after and before specific character

Tags: php, substring

How to get some values after specific character and before specific character and put to array in php

```
$str = "[{"m":[{"a":1,"u":34,"n":"Administrator"}]},
{"m":[{"a":2,"u":3,"n":"Member"}]},
{"m":[{"a":3,"u":44,"n":"Co-Admin"}]},
{"m":[{"a":2,"u":24,"n":"Member"}]},
{"m":[{"a":2,"u":75,"n":"Member"}]}]"
```

I want get all values between `"u":` and `,` in array maybe the result like this `{'34','3','44','24',75}`

Comment: Why not use **json_decode()** ?

Comment: use json_decode($str) and in foreach loop take values like echo $str['m']['u'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get the solution

```
$json = json_decode($str);
foreach ($json as $jkey) {
    foreach($jkey->m as $row)
    {
        $arrayjson[] = $row->u;
    }
}
```

the echo $arrayjson[0] will appear 34 , $arrayjson[1] will appear 3 and etc thank for @shubham715 for the lightbulp in my mind hehe :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use **json_decode** to get value and save into an array.

**Example-**

```
$str = '[{"m":[{"a":1,"u":34,"n":"Administrator"}]},{"m":[{"a":2,"u":3,"n":"Member"}]},{"m":[{"a":3,"u":44,"n":"Co-Admin"}]},{"m":[{"a":2,"u":24,"n":"Member"}]},{"m":[{"a":2,"u":75,"n":"Member"}]}]';

 $getArrayJson = json_decode($str);

 //echo "<pre>"; print_r($getArrayJson);

 $requireValueArray = "";
foreach ($getArrayJson as $getkey => $getvalue) {
    $requireValueArray[] = $getvalue->m[0]->u;

}


$yourjsonDecodeArray = json_encode($requireValueArray);
```

Comment: how to print or echo that array json decode sir ? into {'34','3','44','24',75} @shubham715

Comment: hey @wee.ryo json_encode add curly braces({) on multidimensional array but if you want to add in your array then you can do

`
$yourjsonDecodeArray = json_encode($requireValueArray);
$yourjsonDecodeArray = str_replace("[", "{", $yourjsonDecodeArray);
$yourjsonDecodeArray = str_replace("]", "}" , $yourjsonDecodeArray);
`

and also dont forget to accept answer if its helpful for u :)

Comment: wait.. i mean if i call echo arrayjson[0] the result will appear 34

Comment: you have to first json_decode your array and avoid if you already did then you can do echo arrayjson[0];